# Xcode Server bot build error - Unable to load contents of file list: Target Support Files

Tags: swift, xcode, rubygems, cocoapods, xcode-server

Trying to integrate bot for my UI tests, but always have an error - **Unable to load contents of file list: Target Support Files**

XCode 12

Tried add Pre-integration scripts

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export GEM_HOME="$HOME/.gem"
echo "PATH: $PATH"
 cd /Users/"username"/Desktop/"Projectname"/"directory"
pod install --verbose
```

Also tried

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
echo "PATH: $PATH"
if [ -d ${PODS_DIR} ]; then
    # pods directory exist
    echo "=================="
    echo "   Delete Pods"
    echo "=================="
    # delete cocoapods files if they exist
    rm -rf "${PODS_DIR}"
    eval rm "${BS_SRCROOT}/Podfile.lock"
    eval rm -rf "${BS_SRCROOT}/${BS_EXECUTABLE_NAME}.workspace"
    echo "Deleted Pods directory ${PODS_DIR}"
    echo "Deleted ${BS_EXECUTABLE_NAME}.workspace"
    echo "Deleted Podfile.lock"
else
    echo "Pods NOT detected at ${PODS_DIR}"
fi
echo "=================="
echo "   Install Pods"
echo "=================="
cd <path-to-your-project-folder>
pod install --verbose
```

Have the same error
Scripts works but after raw build have error

I know the server can't find the pods but i can't understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIXED!!!
Xcode Server creates copy of project in the directory:
/Users/username/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Bots/"bot_hash"/Source/"Project name"
And tried start test from **Source** directory instead of **"Project name"** directory

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export GEM_HOME="$HOME/.gem"
echo "PATH: $PATH"
 cd Projectname/directory // change only this line
pod install --verbose
```